# How do you return the response object from ModelAndView when you are using spring forward to redirect to a different controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, forward

I have two Controller classes:

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping( "/controller" )
    public class Controller_Indirect{

        @RequestMapping( "/setContextIndirect" )
        public @ResponseBody ModelAndView setContextIndirect( HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam Message message )
            throws Exception{
        BigMessage bigMessage = new BigMessage();
        bigMessage.setMessage( message );
        bigMessage.setMessageId( "Sample Message ID" );
        return new ModelAndView( "forward:/setContext", "BigMessage", bigMessage );
        }
    }

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping( "/controller2" )
    public class Controller_Direct{

        @RequestMapping( "/setContext" )
        public @ResponseBody JSONOutput setContextDirect( HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody BigMessage bigMessage )
                throws Exception{
            JSONOutput jsonOutput = new JSONOutput();
            OutgoingMessage outgoingMessage = new OutgoingMessage();
            ..
            // Some code
            ..
            jsonOutput.setData( outgoingMessage );
            jsonOutput.setSuccess( true );
            return jsonOutput;
        }
    }
```

The JSONOutput here has two fields data and isSuccess. data is an object returned by the method call - BigMessage
So there is a possibilty to make a call to either one of these Controller methods. The direct method returns a JSONOutput object, and the indirect method returns a ModelAndView object.

Is there any way that I can do this? (get the same JSONOutput as a response from the Direct method which I can then return from the Indirect method):

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping( "/controller" )
    public class Controller_Indirect{

        @RequestMapping( "/setContextIndirect" )
        public @ResponseBody JSONOutput setContextIndirect( HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody Message message ){
        BigMessage bigMessage = new BigMessage();
        bigMessage.setMessage( message );
        bigMessage.setMessageId( "Sample Message ID" );
        JSONOutput jsonOutput = new JSONOutput();
        jsonOutput = (JSONOutput) new ModelAndView( "forward:/setContext", "BigMessage", bigMessage );
        // This JSONOutput should have the OutgoingMessage set as data field.
        return jsonOutput;
        }
    }

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping( "/controller2" )
    public class Controller_Direct{

        @RequestMapping( "/setContext" )
        public @ResponseBody JSONOutput setContextDirect( HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody BigMessage bigMessage ){
            JSONOutput jsonOutput = new JSONOutput();
            OutgoingMessage outgoingMessage = new OutgoingMessage();
            ..
            // Some code
            ..
            jsonOutput.setData( outgoingMessage );
            jsonOutput.setSuccess( true );
            return jsonOutput;
        }
    }
```

Currently, if I do this, `BigMessage bigMessage = (BigMessage) modelAndView.getModel().get( "BigMessage" );`, I get `BigMessage` as the Model Object.

I need this to be `JSONOutput`, which contains `OutgoingMessage`.

Any ideas would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

would you like to get both `modelAndView` and `json` output from the same controller then you might move to `contentNegotiationViewResolver` inorder to get the result.

Comment: I don't need both of them. I just need the JSONOutput object returned.

Comment: How would you like to receive the json output in `modelandview` controller

Comment: It would not be the actual JSON. It would be a Java object called `JSONOutput`. Let's just call it `Output` for now. This will have two fields (`Object data, boolean isSuccess`). Data should be set as the `OutgoingMessage` and returned as the Controller `Output`